# Exporting environment variables in ~/.bash_profile produces wrong values

Tags: macos, command-line, environment-variables

On my MacBook with MacOS Catalina I try to export multiple environment variables by setting them in the `~/.bash_profile` file. I proceed as follows:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
open ~/.bash_profile
```

Then the file `~/.bash_profile` opens in my text editor and I add multiple environment variables:

```
export VAR1="some_value"
export VAR2="some_value"
export VAR3="some_value"
export VAR4="some_value"
export VAR5="some_value"
```

Then I save the file and apply the changes as follows:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now I should be able to access the values of the newly defined variables. If I type `echo ${VAR1}` or `echo ${VAR2}` I get the correct value `some_value`, but if I type `echo ${VAR3}` I get `export$lue`, i.e. the first seven characters are replaced by `export$`.

Any advice?

Comment: What happens if you put different values for VAR1/2/..? Like
export VAR1="some_value1";
export VAR2="some_value2";
export VAR3="some_value3";
export VAR4="some_value4";
export VAR5="some_value5"

Comment: I guess you pasted a carriage return somewhere.

Comment: @BenjaminW. You nailed the issue. Thank you!

Comment: @AndreaCamisa thank you for your suggestion, but duplicate values were not the culprit.

Comment: The canonical Q&A is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39527571/3266847

Comment: I was actually thinking to differentiating the values of the variables to have more feedback / debug. But @BenjaminW is right, carriage return was the problem.